# Accessing struct variable in slice of many structs in html template golang

Tags: templates, go

I'm attempting to send a slice containing many structs to an html template.

I have a 'post' struct

```
type Post struct {
  threadID int
  subject string
  name string
  text string
  date_posted string
}
```

I create a slice of type `Post` ( `posts := []Post{}` )

this slice is then populated using rows from my database and then executed on my template.

```
defer latest_threads.Close()
for latest_threads.Next(){
    var threadID int
    var subject string
    var name string
    var text string
    var date_posted string
    latest_threads.Scan(&threadID, &subject, &name, &text, &date_posted) 
    post := Post{
        threadID,
        subject,
        name,
        text,
        date_posted,
    }
    posts = append(posts, post)
}
t, error := template.ParseFiles("thread.html")
if error != nil{
    log.Fatal(error)
}
t.Execute(w, posts)
}
```

The program compiles / runs okay but when viewing the html output from the template

```
{{.}}
{{range .}}
    <div>{{.threadID}}</div>
    <h3>{{.subject}}</h3>
    <h3>{{.name}}</h3>
    <div>{{.date_posted}}</div>
    <div><p>{{.text}}</p></div>
    <br /><br />
{{end}}
```

`{{.}}` outputs just fine however upon reaching the first `{{.threadID}}` in `{{range .}}` the html stops.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test </title>
</head>
<body>
    //here is where {{.}} appears just fine, removed for formatting/space saving
    <div>
```

Comment: You can't access private structure field from within a template. IIRC that limitation is clearly documented.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not really intuitive, but templates (and encoding packages like JSON, for that matter) can't access unexported data members, so you have to export them somehow:

### Option 1

```
// directly export fields
type Post struct {
    ThreadID int
    Subject, Name, Text, DatePosted string
}
```

### Option 2

```
// expose fields via accessors:
type Post struct {
    threadID int
    subject, name, text, date_posted string
}

func (p *Post) ThreadID()   int    { return p.threadID    }
func (p *Post) Subject()    string { return p.subject     }
func (p *Post) Name()       string { return p.name        }
func (p *Post) Text()       string { return p.text        }
func (p *Post) DatePosted() string { return p.date_posted }
```

---

### Update template

(this part is mandatory regardless of which option you chose from above)

```
{{.}}
{{range .}}
    <div>{{.ThreadID}}</div>
    <h3>{{.Subject}}</h3>
    <h3>{{.Name}}</h3>
    <div>{{.DatePosted}}</div>
    <div><p>{{.Text}}</p></div>
    <br /><br />
{{end}}
```

And this should work.